# WP7 pivot headers stop animating when I scoll too fast

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a pivot control with around 20 items that are data binded to an observable collection. One of these items has a long text inside, and I think it delays a bit to data bind. when i scroll too fast and pass this item, the headers start to behave strange, the highlighted header disappears from the screen and i see the other headers. the animation of headers stops.

How can i fix this? any ideas? You can reproduce this problem on a device.
thanx

Comment: Why do you have 20 items in a pivot?  Can't it possibly be split into multiple pages?  Pivots usually have <= 5 items

Comment: If you'd like us to reproduce its usually the done thing for you to provide some small example for us to replicate.

Comment: well this also happens with 2 or 3 pivot items. the problem is the data binding, and that I scroll the pivot before the data binding is completed. but the behaviour is very strange.

Answer (score 3):

I would have though that having 20 pivot items was more likely to be the cause of the problem, rather than a long pivot title. However, from a user experience point-of-view I would suggest that 20 pivot items is not going to provide a good user experience especially as all pivot items are loaded on when the pivot is started, so performance is likely to be poor, too.

I would suggest that you consider an alternative approach. Perhaps you could use the Panorama to provide a Hub-like experience with your data grouped into different Panorama items. You could then use a Pivot on secondary pages to show group contents where appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you might have the Panorama and the Pivot a bit mixed up.  The Panorama will load all the items, its designed to give the user the feeling they are working in much wider screen than they have.  On the hand a Pivot needs only present the current item. I would be very surprised to find it loading all the items despite only needing to display one of them.

Comment: Sorry, yeah you're right. I still wouldn't advocate a UI that had 20 pivot items, though :)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: The Pivot does fire the `LoadingPivotItem` event for both PivotItems adjacent to the currently displayed one. I was setting the PivotItem bindings in this event and noticed it firing when the item was not in view. The `LoadedPivotItem` event on the other hand, is only fired for the current PivotItem

Comment: Yes I would agree, purely from a UI Design point of view flicking through to the 20th item is quite awkward, not really the design intent of the pivot.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say that I've experienced this, but then I haven't found a need to use a Pivot with 20 pages.

Could it be that if you're finding the need to flick that quikly through the pages that another UX would be more appropriate?

Perhaps a listbox to present a choice of items allowing ultra smooth and fast scrolling, from which the user can choose to select an item and drill down for details.

The databound project template provides some out of the box handling to demonstrate the concept, but don't be show to roll your own in a vanilla project template.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue with a pivot control with only 4 pivot items. The animation gets screwed up when the pivot item containing a long list is selected, so I'm guessing that because pivots don't load their data until the item is selected, that the pivot control is getting screwed up trying to load the long list while animating...so it gives up on the animation.

I haven't really figured out what to do about this yet. One solution is to not bind the data in the pivot item until that item is selected. This isn't really ideal, but it would likely solve the animation issue.